# How I can show the latest post at the top in Django template using example.example_set.all

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to present all the post information in the profile and I'm using this command below to do it in the template as a template tag

```
{% for letter in user.letter_set.all %}
```

Profiles view code in view.py

```
class UserProfilePage(DetailView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    model = Profile

    def get_object(self):
        username = self.kwargs.get("username")
        if username is None:
            raise Http404
        return get_object_or_404(User, username__iexact=username, is_active=True)
```

It's working but I need to show the latest post at the top. Please tell me how I can do it. I think I have to make some changes to the template tag. 
TIA

Comment: So how do you store your `Letter` objects? Do you want to order them by a special field, say `posted_on`? or you just need reversed id sorting?

Comment: Couple options. Look at prefetch_related and you can add a custom queryset so you can sort the data. Or you can add a default ordering to your Letter model, see class meta.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to have letters ordering, which will go from the newest to the oldest. If it is you're looking for than add the ordering field in Meta class in Letter model as follows:

```py
class Letter(models.Model):
    ...
    some other fields
    ...
    date = models.DateTimeField(...)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

'-' before *date* (or the other date field which keeps the date in your model) tells Django to show Letter instances starting from the latest.

The other code will be valid without any changes.